# MongoDB: Query matching subdocument field?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following document:

```
  {
   _id: ,
   players:[
   {player_id: ,
   answer: ,
   },
   {player_id:
   answer:
   }, ... 
   ]
   }
```

I want to return the answer of the matching player_id.
I tried to build on query using the projection operator $ without success:

```
 Game.findOne({"players.player_id": Meteor.userId()}, {"players.$": 1});
```

This is supposed to return only one element in the array players, but it returns all.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Found on the meteor documentation:

Field operators such as $ and $elemMatch are not available on the client side yet.

http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers

Comment: But I think there should be a way to bypass meteor and use the native driver. Check if you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Game.findOne({"players.player_id": Meteor.userId()}, {"players": {$elemMatch: {player_id: Meteor.userId() }}});
```

should work. Search mongodb projection $elemMatch. I am on mobile, will give you the relevant documentation later